# Nodejs-mysql pool connection not working with async series

Tags: mysql, node.js, async.js

The following is a code snippet of my node script:

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, maria_connection) {

        maria_connection.query(' CREATE TABLE Currency(uuid VARCHAR(10),name VARCHAR(12),PRIMARY KEY(uuid), UNIQUE(name))')
        async.series({
                one: function(callback){
                    var currency_ids = []

                        request('host_url', function (error, response, html) {
                          if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                            .....used maria_connection here to save some data
                          }
                        })
                    setTimeout( function(){
                      callback(null, 1);
                    },20000)
                 },
                 two: function(callback){
                     maria_connection.query({
                      sql: 'SELECT uuid FROM Currency'
                      },
                      function (error, results, fields){
                        console.log(error)
                        add_currencies( results )
                      }
                    )
                       setTimeout( function(){
                        callback(null, 2);
                       },20000)
                 },
                 three: function(callback){
                       console.log('third series called')
                       maria_connection.query({
                          sql: 'SELECT * FROM Brokers'
                          },
                          function (error, results, fields){
                             if (error) throw error;
                            console.log(results)
                          }
                       )
                      setTimeout( function(){
                        callback(null, 3);
                       },20000)
                 },
                 four: function(callback){ process.exit(-1); }
        }, function(error, results) { // <--- this is the main callback
                maria_connection.release();
        });
```

Now the first two items in series works fine,but when third function is called the console log prints the text 'third series called' but maria_connection doesn't works. It doesn't even throw any error.

Comment: Try error logging before maria_connection.release();

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are using `async.js` properly with your use of `throw()` and `setTimeout()`. You shouldn't need to use neither of them.

For example, your use of `setTimeout()` assumes that the current task will take at most 20 seconds -- but what if it doesn't? If you call `callback()`, you will start the next task before the current task has completed. You might run two queries at the same time (which defeats the idea of using `async.series()`).

Better to make trigger `callback()` when you are guaranteed that the task is done (or comes back with an error). And if an error occurs, instead of throwing it, pass it in the `callback` so that it can gracefully stop the `async.series()`.

```
async.series({
    one: function(callback){
        var currency_ids = []
        request('host_url', function (error, response, html) {
            if (error)
                return callback(error);
            if (response.statusCode != 200) 
                return callback(new Error('not 200'));
            // .....used maria_connection here to save some data (*)
        });
    },
    two: function(callback){
        maria_connection.query({ sql: 'SELECT uuid FROM Currency' }, function (error, results, fields){
            if (error)
                return callback(error);
            add_currencies(results); // (*)
        });
    },
    three: function(callback){
        console.log('third series called')
        maria_connection.query({ sql: 'SELECT * FROM Brokers' }, function (error, results, fields){
            if (error)
                return callback(error);
            console.log(results)
            callback();
        });
    }
}, function(error, results) {
    // if an error occurs, it will come down here
    // if all tasks are completed successfully, it will also come down here too
    console.log(error, results); 
    maria_connection.release(); 
    process.exit(-1);
});
```

If `(*)` is an async operation, make sure you call the callback when the operation is finished. For example, if `add_currencies()` is an async operation, you most likely want to write it like

```
function add_currencies(results, callback) {
    doAsyncOperation(results, function (error) {
        if (error)
            return callback(error);
        callback();
    });

    // or simply doAsyncOperation(results, callback);
}
```

The important point is always trigger the `callback` at least and at most once within each task. If not, usually things to start to hang.